# How to initialize 2D array of string in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialized 2D array of string in c++.

```
std::string A = new std::string [m+1][n+1]
```

But this is giving me error as array size in new-expression must be constant.

Comment: This is C++, use vectors `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> A(...)`.

Comment: In c++ you should use `std::vector` or `std::array`  instead of  those `new any_type[m][n]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing a two dimensional array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4612328/608639), [How can i declare and init two dimensional array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16836595/608639), etc.

Comment: VLAs (variable length array don't exist in C++)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the C-Style String way...

```
char ** array = new char*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
     array[i] = new char[100];
}
```

Then you just delete it in the opposite order you created it when done.

Using the STL is probably a good choice if you need to be safe and modern.